# How to emulate curl --data 'some_content=xyz' on Play Framework?

Tags: java, web-services, curl, playframework

I've been testing some external API and this curl command works perfectly to interact with the API's endpoint:

```
curl -i -L -H 'Accept: application/json' --data 'client_id=11111111&client_secret=2222222222' 'https://some.api.com/endpoint'
```

However, I haven't been able to emulate this same call on Play Framework. No matter what I try, the external API still returns an error saying that "client_id is empty". This error doesn't occur when I use the curl command, so I have to conclude that there's something wrong with the way I'm doing it with the Play Framework.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
// Using the parameters directly in the endpoint

String data = "client_id=" + MY_CLIENT_ID;
data += "&client_secret=" + MY_CLIENT_SECRET;

WSRequestHolder request = WS.url("https://some.api.com/endpoint/" + data);
request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");

Promise<Result> promise = request.post("").map(new Function<WS.Response, Result>() { ... }
```

A different test:

```
// Using the data input as JSON

ObjectNode node = Json.newObject();
node.put("client_id", MY_CLIENT_ID);
node.put("client_secret", MY_CLIENT_SECRET);

WSRequestHolder request = WS.url("https://some.api.com/endpoint/");
request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");

Promise<Result> promise = request.post(node).map(new Function<WS.Response, Result>() {...}
```

I also tried to convert the data string and the JSON node into an InputStream as such:

```
ByteArrayInputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(node.toString().getBytes());
```

And then using it as such:

```
Promise<Result> promise = request.post(input).map(new Function<WS.Response, Result>() {...}
```

The result is always the "client_id is empty" error.

I'm using Play 2.1.5 (with Java).

I appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost got it.
Try

```
WS.url("http://localhost:9000/echo").
            setFollowRedirects(true).
            setHeader("Accept", "application/json").
            setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded").
          post("client_id=11111111&client_secret=2222222222");
```

- curl -L -> setFollowRedirect(true) Not sure if -i will work as in curl
- curl --data -> Adds content type header

Comment: Brilliant! That's it. Thanks, mate.